# git remove a commit from pull request

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-cherry-pick

I'm newbie to open source contribution, so it one of my first tries.

I developed a library (gem) called `validates`: https://github.com/kaize/validates/

I made 2 branches through `git checkout -b branch_name`:

https://github.com/kaize/validates/pull/20 & https://github.com/kaize/validates/pull/19, and make commits for them, but, you can see that ip-validator pull request have a commit `Blank validator` `399cdd7`.

What I need to do to remove it from this pull request (and still place in blank validator branch)?

Please help me with make world better, guys!

Comment: Have you tried rebasing?? git rebase -i

Comment: What exactly I need to rebase?

Comment: man git-rebase would explain all you need to know about rebasing

Comment: I thing you have to just not apply the pull request. Just close it, instead of it you shell to open a new proper pull request. I guess it is feature of github.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

On the `ip-validator` branch, you'd do `git rebase -i HEAD~2` - this will start an interactive rebase back two commits on that branch.

At this point, you'll get an editor open with options seen here: https://help.github.com/articles/interactive-rebase

Simply put, to remove that commit, just delete the commit line in the editor, save that editor file, and git will create a new commit without the commit you removed.

Comment: You could then force a push to github to overwrite changes already pushed.

Comment: Note: for this to work I was needed to `git push -f origin` *(note `-f`)*, otherwise it asks you to pull the repo first, pulls actually won't help.